# I cannot adjust brightness in Lenovo G580 laptop windows 10

Tags: windows-10, lenovo-laptop

I have lenovo G580 laptop. I had installed Windows 10. After installing Windows 10 I could't adjust screen brightness

Comment: Is the battery button on the bottom right? That's how.

Answer (score 0):

I have found this solution for you

> Go to Start Menu > Search and type Device Manager.
>
> Then launch the Device Manager app and navigate to the Display
>   adapters section. Just expand this option and right-click on the
>   installed display driver.
>
> Then select Update Driver Software from the ensuing context menu.
>
> Select Search automatically for updated driver software in the
>   resulting interface menu.
>
> Windows 10 should automatically download and install the necessary
>   display or video card drivers via the detected internet connection.
>
> Once the drivers are installed successfully, you will see a
>   notification message confirming the same along with the hardware
>   details pertaining to the driver.

Source:
http://www.ibtimes.co.uk/how-fix-windows-10-brightness-control-not-working-issue-1514636

Comment: Please read [How to reference material written by others](http://superuser.com/help/referencing). 
You should block quote text that has been written by some else. See [Markdown help](https://superuser.com/editing-help).
I've fixed it for you this time, but please pay attention to this in future.